# Assembler для x64 windows 7

Tags: ассемблер, компилятор, x86-64

Подскажите компилятор ассемблера для windows 7 x64

Comment: Эээ, не совсем понятен вопрос. Нужен любой или именно 64-битовый?

Comment: 64 нужен...

Comment: gcc не подойдет ?  Он ест ассемблер в .s файлах.

Answer (score 4):

Попробуйте [Fasm](http://flatassembler.net/). Он точно 64 битность поддерживает, работает под множеством платформ (в том числе и винда). Для винды в стандартной поставке есть минимальное IDE с gui.

Answer (score 1):

Вроде как бы MASM есть 64-битовый.

Comment: Я не нашел, или находил, но там только source файлы.

Answer (score 1):

Во время учёбы в университете я и мои однокурсники не могли найти компилятор для 64-разрядных систем. Проблема решалось путём поднятия виртуальной машины с 32 разрядной windows. https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads

Answer (score -3):

запустить как....

объясняю

СВОЙСТВА - СОВМЕСТИМОСТЬ - ЗАПУСТИТЬ ПРОГРАММУ В...